# jquery.nicescroll with wrong tabindex value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nicescroll

I followed [jQuery.NiceScroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) to edit scrollbar. Normally, when I call `$(selector).niceScroll()`, it will append `tabindex` and some css properties into the selector. Like this:

```
$('p.lead').niceScroll({autohidemode: false});
```

[image: p]

Then, 2 divs which id starts with `ascrail` will be appended to `<body>`, too.

[image: _p]

As you can see: if `tabindex` is `5000`, 2 new ids will be `ascrail2000` and `ascrail2000-hr`.

That mean we can access the `<div>`'s via:

```
var id = 2000 + (+$('p.lead').prop('tabindex') - 5000);
var vertical = $('div#ascrail' + id);
var horizontal = $('div#ascrail' + id + '-hr');

//do stuff...
```

That's good until I use [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) to show some divs as a popup:

```
<div class="new-topic">
  <!-- another divs -->

  <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
    <div class="n-images">          
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- another divs -->
</div>
```

Script:

```
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('div.new-topic'),
        css: {
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
            border: 'none',
            cursor: 'default',
            borderRadius: '5px',
            width: ''
        }
    });
    $('div.n-images').niceScroll({autohidemode: false});
```

Then, I viewed the page souce, `tabindex` was overridden:

[image: i]

But it's not for `div[id^="ascrail"]`:

[image: _i]

Now, how can I change css property `z-index` in `div#ascrail2001` and `div#ascrail2001-hr`?

This way won't work correctly:

```
//this will return 2000 instead of 2001
var id = 2000 + (+$('div.n-images').prop('tabindex') - 5000);

//if I can get the id correctly, every thing will became easy:
//change z-index: auto -> z-index: 10001 
//because if z-index is smaller than 10000, it won't appear

$('div#ascrail' + id).css('z-index', 10001);
$('div#ascrail' + id + '-hr').css('z-index', 10001);
```

My problem is: `$(selector).niceScroll()` didn't check for existing tabindex value and update new tabindex value. (existing value: 5000, new value: 5001).

So, my question is: How to update new value to tabindex in this case?

p/s: I'm using mvc 5. `<p class="lead">` is in another partial view which different from `<div class="n-images">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. That's because I have added

```
<script src"~/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
```

twice in 2 partial views.

I tried to remove them, open `BundleConfig.cs` in `App_Start` folder and added this line:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/nicescroll").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.js"));
```

It should work. Thanks for reading!